# Querying on mysql docker container via python, throwing timeout error after few hours

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Inserting via debezium connector to mysql database brought up via docker container.

Trying to query and it is working fine until some number of hours. But, after that, same query is throwing below exception.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/tmp/tests/artifacts/java-17/jdk-17; export PATH=$PATH:/tmp/tests/artifacts/java-17/jdk-17/bin; docker exec -i mysql_be1e6a mysql --user=demo --password=demo -D demo -e "select count(k) from test_cdc_f0bf84 where uuid = 'd1e5cd6d-8f7a-457c-b2ea-880c2be52f69'"
```

```
2023-01-02 16:27:43,812:ERROR: failed to execute query MySQL rows count by uuid: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/stress_tests/run_test_with_universe/src/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 699, in recv
    out = self.in_buffer.read(nbytes, self.timeout)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/stress_tests/run_test_with_universe/src/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/buffered_pipe.py", line 164, in read
    raise PipeTimeout()
paramiko.buffered_pipe.PipeTimeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/stress_tests/run_test_with_universe/src/suites/cdc/abstract.py", line 667, in try_query
    res = query_function()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/stress_tests/run_test_with_universe/src/suites/cdc/test_cdc.py", line 635, in <lambda>
    query = lambda: self.mysql_query(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/stress_tests/run_test_with_universe/src/suites/cdc/abstract.py", line 544, in mysql_query
    result = self.ssh.exec_on_host(host, [
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/stress_tests/run_test_with_universe/src/main/connection.py", line 335, in exec_on_host
    return self._exec_on_host(host, commands, fetch, timeout=timeout, limit_output=limit_output)[host]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/stress_tests/run_test_with_universe/src/main/connection.py", line 321, in _exec_on_host
    res = list(out)
          ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/stress_tests/run_test_with_universe/src/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 125, in __next__
    line = self.readline()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/stress_tests/run_test_with_universe/src/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 291, in readline
    new_data = self._read(n)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/stress_tests/run_test_with_universe/src/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1361, in _read
    return self.channel.recv(size)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/stress_tests/run_test_with_universe/src/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 701, in recv
    raise socket.timeout()
TimeoutError
```

After some time, logged manually to machine and tried to read, it still reads fine. Not sure, what does this issue mean.

As explained, tried querying from database via python. Expected it will return count of rows, which it was happening until certain time, but after that, it threw timeout error and socket error.

Comment: Which image are you using? If you built it yourself, also show what the dockerfile looks like. It's not possible to know where it is going wrong if we don't know what software you're running.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to query and it is working fine until some number of hours. But, after that, same query is throwing below exception.

The default value for `interactive_timeout` and `wait_timeout` is [28880 seconds (8 hours)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout). you can disable this behavior by setting this system variable to zero in your MySQL config.

source: [Configuring session timeouts](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-session-timeouts)